# How to write an "if/unless" statement for an integer variable based on the ultimate and penultimate values?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to write a conditional where if a ends in 1 then it will answer with "st root" unless it ends with an 11 so it will be like 1st root or 11th root
(Then also work in similar ways for 2/12 and 3/13)

Here is the code I have tried

```
    def n():
      print("Only enter whole numbers\n ")
      base = float(input("Enter number to take the root of, then hit enter:\n "))
      input_string = input("Enter degree of roots (if more than one, separate by space) then hit enter:\n ")
      list  = input_string.split()
      a = 1
      for num in list:
          base **= (1/float(num))
      for num in list:
          a *= int(num)
      if str(a)[-1] == '1':
        if str(a)[-1] != '11':
          print(a,"st root",base) 
      elif str(a)[-1] == '2':
        if str(a)[-1] != '12':
          print(a,"nd root",base)
      elif str(a)[-1] == '3':
        if str(a)[-1] != '13':
          print(a,"rd root",base)
      else: 
        print(a,"th root",base)
    n()
```

Comment: Can you give sample input and output?

Comment: What is your question about this code?

Comment: There are three places in your code where you are checking for equivalency between one character and two characters. This will never be true.

Comment: A sample input would be entering 8 for the first prompt and 3 for the second, then the output would be 3rd root = 2. The problem I have is when I will do something like an 11th root, the program will give me 11st root = 1.208... when I would want it to be 11th and not 11st (Same for 12th instead of 12nd and 13th instead of 13rd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can almost translate your sentence directly into code:

> if lastCharacter is 1 and not penUltimateCharacter is 1

so:

```
if (str(a)[-1] == '1' and str(a)[-2] != '1'):
   print(a,"st root",base)
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I understand the [-1] and [-2] now, its referring to the position of the value from the right. Thank you, I see the problem now

Comment: Yes I forgot to explain it, but it indeed references to the n'th (or in this case counting from right to left) character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer for converting integers to ordinal numbers.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41298/producing-ordinal-numbers

Here is the final code snippet

```
# much code can be improved by using a datastructe.
SUFFIXES = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
def ordinal(num):
    # I'm checking for 10-20 because those are the digits that
    # don't follow the normal counting scheme. 
    if 10 <= num % 100 <= 20:
        suffix = 'th'
    else:
        # the second parameter is a default.
        suffix = SUFFIXES.get(num % 10, 'th')
    return str(num) + suffix
```

Comment: Would I place this after the "for num in list: a *= int(num)"?

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially need is the last digit and the last two digits as a number:

```
a = 1234 #My number to check
last_digit = a - int(a/10)*10
two_two_last_digits = a - int(a/100)*100
```

Now, these two numbers have the nice relationship, that they difference is 10 whenever your connection is met, so you have:

```
if (two_last_digits - last_digit) != 10:
    ...
```

So with the 'unless' part covered, the if part can be expressed using a dict:

```
cases = {1: "st root ", 2:"nd root", 3:"rd root"}
```

Taking all things together we get:

```
if (two_last_digits - last_digit) != 10:
    print(a, "th root", base)
else:
    try:
        print(a, cases[last_digit], base)
    except KeyError:
        print(a, "th root", base)
```